# Replace ^ and _ with <sup> and <sub>

Tags: javascript, regex

I need to be able to replace `^{value}` with `<sup>value</sup>` and `_{value}` with `<sub>value</sub>`. I haven't been using regular expressions for that before (only for testing expressions), and can't seem to figure out exactly how to do it. Any hints?

Best regards

Comment: Please add your sample data on which we can work..

Comment: and what you tried so far!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Hint #1: You'll be using the [`String.replace()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace) function here, specifically with a regex match and a string replacement.

Hint #2: You will need to escape the `^` and `{}` characters. You will also need to capture the "value", perhaps with something like `(.*?)`

Hint #3: Use the `g` modifier.

Hint #4: Once you've captured the value, you can use it in the replacement string with `$1`

Hint #5: Don't try to do both superscript and subscript at once. Do them one after the other.

Full solution: on [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/1c4pzads/), don't look until you've tried yourself using the hints!

Comment: those are a lot of hints :P